# QAbstractItemModel confused about index/parent and data functions

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have the following simple model example:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QTreeView>
#include <QAbstractItemModel>

class TestModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
public:
    TestModel()
    {
        SetUpData();
    }

    virtual QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex& parent) const
    {
        if ( parent.isValid())
        {
            // child
            return createIndex( row, column, (void*)&mData[row].mChildren[column]);
        }
        // root
        return createIndex( row, column, (void*)&mData[row]);
    }

    virtual QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex& child) const
    {
        ModelData* data = (ModelData*)child.internalPointer();

        // find out where "data" is in the mData vector structure
        for ( size_t i=0; i<mData.size(); ++i )
        {
            for ( size_t j=0; j<mData[i].mChildren.size(); ++j )
            {
                if ( &mData[i].mChildren[j] == data )
                {
                    // I think this is correct, return the parent row at col 0?
                    return createIndex( i, 0, (void*)&mData[i].mChildren[j]);
                }
            }
        }
        return QModelIndex();
    }

    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
    {
        if ( parent.isValid() )
        {
            // Per root node size
            return mData[parent.row()].mChildren.size();
        }

        // Root size
        return mData.size();
    }

    virtual int columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
    {
        // The "parent" nodes should have two columns, the children should have 1
        if ( parent.isValid() )
        {
            // Root
            return 1;
        }
        // Children
        return 2;
    }

    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
    {
        if ( role == Qt::DisplayRole && index.isValid() )
        {
            if ( index.isValid() )
            {
                // I think col and row are the wrong way around, but will crash if swapped
                return mData[index.column()].mChildren[index.row()].mName;
            }
            else
            {
                // this never happens because "RootN" is never displayed
                return mData[index.column()].mName;
            }
        }
        return QVariant();
    }

private:
    // The "real" data that this Qt model is providing an interface to
    struct ModelData
    {
        QString mName;
        std::vector< ModelData > mChildren;
    };

    std::vector< ModelData > mData;

    void SetUpData()
    {
        for ( int i=0; i<3; ++i )
        {
            ModelData root;
            root.mName = "Root" + QString::number( i+1 );

            for ( int j=0; j<10; ++j )
            {
                ModelData node;
                node.mName = "Node" + QString::number( j+1 );
                root.mChildren.push_back( node );
            }
            mData.push_back( root );
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    TestModel* model = new TestModel();
    QTreeView* tv = new QTreeView();

    tv->setModel( model );
    tv->show();

    int ret = a.exec();

    delete tv;
    delete model;

    return ret;
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is create a model which has the following structure:

```
Root1
 |-Node1-10
 |
Root2
 |-Node1-10
 |
Root3
 |-Node1-10
```

However I end up with this:

[image: output]

I'm really confused about how index/parent and data are supposed to be working. Obviously I don't understand it because my output is incorrect.

I thought that for example, Root1, Node3 would cause index to be called with row = 0, col=2, at which point I call createIndex with 0,2 and the pointer to that element?

And for parent() return QModelIndex if parent is valid as this means its a RootN element, then return createIndex to create an index to the parent if its not a root element.

Finally for data I figured this just returns the display string for the UI for the given row/column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought that for example, Root1, Node3 would cause index to be
>   called with row = 0, col=2, at which point I call createIndex with 0,2
>   and the pointer to that element?

No.  Your tree has only two columns: col 0 shows the tree hierarchy, and col 1 displays the labels again.  So calling col 2 is just invalid.

Root1, Node3 should have a row=2 col=(1/2, whichever you wanted) and a parent index equal to row=0, col=(1/2) with an invalid parent (an invalid parent means you are at root level).

What `data(..)` returns depends on what `role` is passed to it, see the [documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) for types you should be interested in.

Comment: I'm still confused about this - are you saying all elements should be thought of as a "flat" list? for example:

    Root1 r0, c0,
     Node1 r1, c0,
     Node2 r2, c0,
    Root2 r3, c0

etc?

Comment: No, I think you are confusing the 'branches' of your tree with columns.  The columns display different bits of data from each entry in your model, each row is an entry.  The tree is addressed like layered tables (each individually is flat), to access the root elements the user would pass an invalid parent index to `index(..)`, to access Root2-Node1, you would pass the index of root 2 as the parent and row=0 as the row (the column would just be which bit of data you would be interested in).

Comment: I see, so QModelIndex r0, c0 with invalid parent would be Root1, QModelIndex r0, c0 with a parent of r0, c0 would be Node1. And QModelIndex r2, c0 with a parent of r1, c0 would be Node3 with parent Root2?

Comment: That's right - it's a bit confusing at first, but it scales nicely and can apply to any multi-layered 2D model.